# dependency hell: installing Sonata User

Tags: php, json, symfony, sonata

G'day all, I'm afraid yet another newbie is stuck trying to glue all the bits together. It's rather frustrating, to say the least :(

I've searched these forums, and see countless possible solutions, but none have worked so far. Most also also quite old, and versions have moved on.

Here we go:

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html

When I try this: `composer require sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle`

I get this:

> Using version ^2.1 for sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle
>   ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package sonata-project/admin-bundle == 2.3.7.0 could not be found.   Problem 2
>       - Can only install one of: sonata-project/block-bundle[2.3.8, 2.2.13].
>       - Can only install one of: sonata-project/block-bundle[2.3.8, 2.2.13].
>       - Can only install one of: sonata-project/block-bundle[2.3.8, 2.2.13].
>       - sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/block-bundle ^2.3.8 -> satisfiable by
>   sonata-project/block-bundle[2.3.8].
>       - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[dev-master].
>       - Installation request for sonata-project/block-bundle == 2.2.13.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/block-bundle[2.2.13].
>
> Potential causes:- A typo in the package name  - The
>   package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your
>   minimum-stability setting
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

I'm just following instructions, plain and simple! I read those articles, and tried a few solutions here, and via a Google search.

For what it's worth, I'm an old Unix hacker from way back, and I don't remember open source builds being this hard ...

Any clues? Many thanks in advance!

p.s. I'm using a Debian virtual box, as I thought it'd be easier than trying things on my Windows 8 PC.

**Here is the only changed section from composer.json:**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

Comment: Do you run this command in empty dir?

Comment: I just followed the instructions on the Sonata web site. That's why I'm confused. I've not even written any custom code.

I just want to get the basics working before I start writing my app.

Comment: Can you update your question with the content of your `composer.json` file? Maybe you'll need to specify an alternative version of the package.

Comment: Looking at your description: `Problem 1 - The requested package sonata-project/admin-bundle == 2.3.7.0 could not be found.` Maybe there is a typo in the related `composer.json` file. SonataAdminBundle **can't** be version 2.3.7.0, but 2.3.7 or 2.3.0

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. This is the only section I've changed, as per instructions:

Comment: Having sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1" as well as sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master" in composer.json is asking for trouble. Remove one. Use a stable version, not dev-master

Comment: Thanks, removed, no change. Again, I'm just copying and pasting and executing form the instructions. How can it be this hard?!

Comment: As @JessevanMuijden pointed out, you have `sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle` duplicated (last line and 3º line from the bottom), remove the last line (which says `"sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master"`) and re-run `composer update`. Then, feedback, please.

Comment: Yes, thanks, as I said, I removed one, no joy, so I removed the other, no joy.

I've tried every combination I can find using Google, and so far, nothing helps.

Comment: Check out my answer, it worked for me (I started a test project just to probe it), so it should also work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Empty the `vendor` folder: Delete everything on it, but don't delete itself. Maybe a broken downloaded dependency is causing you issues.

**2.** Replace your `require` section of your `composer.json` with this one:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^2.2"
},
```

Notice the difference about `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle"` version.

Now it should work! Let me know if it's still causing you issues.

Comment: **Thanks! Tried that, got this when running via browser:**

InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 309: 
Unrecognized options "naming_strategy, auto_mapping" under "doctrine.orm"

Comment: That's another thing related to what you have written in `app/config.yml`, is not related to dependencies, nor to `composer`. If my answer helped you, accept it. Then, we can resolve other issues opening another separated question.